# Converting PHP cell value to date

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

PHPExcel is giving me different date value formats on same sheet template

This is the code I use

```
$value = $this->worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, 1)  ->getFormattedValue();
$this->_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("j/n/Y",$value);
```

I've tried the following answers but they didn't solve it

[PHPEXCEL get formatted date as is visible in excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603451/phpexcel-get-formatted-date-as-is-visible-in-excel-file)

[how to get date from excel using PHPExcel library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674633/how-to-get-date-from-excel-using-phpexcel-library)

This is a problem I encountered and I hope I can help somebody else who also has this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an Excel serialized timestamp value directly to a PHP DateTime object, without needing to create a formatted string, and then create a new DateTime object from that:

```
$msExcelSerializedTimestampValue = $this->worksheet
    ->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, 1)
    ->getCalculatedValue();  // getValue() is even easier if the cell doesn't contain a formula
$this->_date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($msExcelSerializedTimestampValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

This solved it for me

```
$value = $this->worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, 1)  ->getCalculatedValue();
$timeValue = (string)PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($value,PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);
$this->_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$timeValue);
```