# PHPExcel date to string

Tags: date, phpexcel

How i cant use the date from an excel.
I use a for loop to output the file

```
echo $sheet -> getCellByColumnAndRow($j,$i)->getValue();
```

But the output looks like that:

```
 Date  |  Name
---------------
425831 |  Peter
425831 |  Nils
```

How i get something like that 2016-08.01?

Comment: `getFormattedValue()` might be better than `getValue()`, as (unles you've specified loadDataOnly as true when loading the file, then it will convert that MS Excel serialized timestamp to a formatted string reflecting the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is seconds from 1970. Try something similar to this, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19675291/5168927):

```
$cell = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $i);
$InvDate= $cell->getValue();
if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
    $InvDate = date($format, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($InvDate));
}
```

You can however also just convert it in PHP with this:

```
date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($sheet -> getCellByColumnAndRow(1,12)->getValue()));
```

Comment: i tried echo date('Y-m-d',$sheet -> getCellByColumnAndRow(1,12)->getValue()); i got 1970-01-01. but why

Comment: `seconds from 1870`.... days from 1-Jan-1900 (or 1904 on Mac) in fact; that's an MS Excel Serialized timestamp, not a Unix timestamp

Comment: Didnt saw the link echo date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($sheet -> getCellByColumnAndRow(1,12)->getValue())); works. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MarkBaker I wasn't even aware MS used their own standard.